# Exclude part of the string with regex

Tags: regex, url, regular-language

I'm quite bad with regex, and I'm looking to match a criteria.
This is a regex expression that should go emmbed into the url for a firewall, so It will block any url that is not like the list at the end.

This is what Im currently using but its not working:

```
http://www.youtube.com/(*.*)list=UUFwtOm4N5djdcuTAlNIWJaQ
```

This is the example url (to be blocked):

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?NR=1&feature=fvwp&v=P1b5VY_Bp_o&list=UUFwtOm4N5djdcuTAlNIWJaQ
```

I'm trying to make a regex that will Success fully match when `NR=1` or `feature=fvwp` 
are NOT present, I asume I can do it like this: `(?!^feature=fvwp$)` but the `v=` and `list=UUFwtOm4N5djdcuTAlNIWJaQ` are allowed.

Also the v= should be limited to any character (uppercase and lowercase) and 11 length, I assume its: `/^[a-z0-9]{11}$/`

How can I build all that together and make it work so it would allow and match only on this urls excluding from allowing the previous criterias that I explained:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4eK_RWpTgcc&feature=BFa&list=UUFwtOm4N5djdcuTAlNIWJaQ

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TLRl85TJwZM&feature=BFa&list=UUFwtOm4N5djdcuTAlNIWJaQ

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QEV9yqrpxkc&feature=BFa&list=UUFwtOm4N5djdcuTAlNIWJaQ
```

Comment: Why can't you block the whole of `www.youtube.com`?

Comment: @adarshr `so It will block any url that is not like the list at the end.`

Comment: Because we need to allow the videos on `list=UUFwtOm4N5djdcuTAlNIWJaQ` but the problem is that when you finish watching a video from the list, you can select another foreign video from the emmbed player, so it keeps the `list=UUFwtOm4N5djdcuTAlNIWJaQ` in the url but it adds this criteria: `NR=1&feature=fvwp`.

Comment: @DavidB I know. I was just questioning the point of letting one just browse youtube.com without being able to actually watch any videos!

Comment: If it's small enough, I'd just download the videos to a server and then block youtube.com.

Comment: That is not the solution that I can provide, I need to block it through a firewall regex expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you block based *on matching* by regex? If so, just use
`(.*)www\.youtube\.com/watch\?NR=1&feature=fvwp` and block whatever matches that.

Comment: `http://www.youtube.com/(?!.*list=UUFwtOm4N5djdcuTAlNIWJaQ)` is not matching with `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4eK_RWpTgcc&feature=BFa&list=UUFwtOm4N5djdcuTAlNIWJaQ` which is an allowed url, either with `http://www.youtube.com/watch?NR=1&feature=fvwp&v=P1b5VY_Bp_o&list=UUFwtOm4N5djdcuTAlNIWJaQ` which is the not allowed url. 
The regex should check if `NR=1` or `feature=fvwp` are present, and validate / match only if they are not present but the real url is: `watch?v=TLRl85TJwZM&feature=BFa&list=UUFwtOm4N5djdcuTAlNIWJaQ` where `v=` is `/^[a-z0-9]{11}$/`

Comment: I should block `http://www.youtube.com/watch?NR=1&feature=fvwp` but allow `v=` beign a-z0-9 and 11 chars length + `list=UUFwtOm4N5djdcuTAlNIWJaQ`

Comment: @BoDiE2003 What I'm saying is if you *have* a match, *disallow* that URL.

Comment: How to I disallow `NR=1&feature=fvwp` but allow `v=/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{11}$/&feature=BFa&list=UUFwtOm4N5djdcuTAlNIWJaQ` on the same url?

Comment: @BoDiE2003 No problem- the only issue is people can still manually type in youtube videos and what not. I only tackled your edge case- I wouldn't recommend using regex as a firewall solution because people can use proxies/malformed URLs. It's a cat-and-mouse game you'll always lose.